# How to return indices of values in Dictionary with enumerate?

Tags: python, function, sorting, dictionary, enumerate

There is a function that takes input as some bounding boxes and sorts these boxes according to their dimensions. I use a Dict which has a reference box and list of all other bounding boxes. The function sorts and returns bounding boxes in sequence. But I need to return the indices of the bounding boxes and not the boxes itself.

Following is the part of code which needs to be adapted to get the indices:

```
def sort_nodes_into_lines(
    nodes: Iterable[graphanno.Node],
) -> Tuple[Tuple[Tuple[int, graphanno.Node],...],...]:

  nodes_sorted = sorted(nodes, key=lambda node: node.box.origin_x)
(reference_idx, reference), *remainder = enumerate(nodes_sorted)
lines: Dict[Tuple[int, graphanno.Node], List[Tuple[int, graphanno.Node]]] = {(reference_idx, reference): [(reference_idx, reference)]}
for node_idx, node in remainder:
    is_matched = False
    for (reference_idx, reference), line in lines.items():
        if _has_sufficient_y_overlap(reference, node):
            *_, (_,last_in_row) = line
            if _in_x_proximity(last_in_row, node):
                line.append((node_idx, node))
                is_matched = True
                break
    if not is_matched:
        lines[(node_idx, node)] = [(node_idx, node)]

return tuple(sorted((tuple(line) for line in lines.values()),key=_get_line_origin_x))




def _get_line_origin_x(line: Sequence[Tuple[int, graphanno.Node]]) -> int:
    """Find min value of y coordinate of the origin of the bounding box."""

    return min(node.box.origin_y for _, node in line)
```

Comment: Hi. If you paste code in your question, please make it reproducible. Here if I try to run your code as you have shown it, I'll get many error messages. For instance variable `lines` is not defined.

Comment: *"I use a Dict which has a reference box and list of all other bounding boxes."* This description of the dict would be a lot easier to understand if you show us an example of such a dict.

Comment: Addressing to your first question, lines is "lines: Dict[Node, List[Node]] = {reference: [reference]}" so when I refer to bounding box it is a Node, which has the following arguments like, Node("text", width, height)

Comment: Can you give an example of such a dict? Perhaps with at most 5 boxes in it.

Comment: I changed the code and is able to return both the indices and the nodes, but I want to return them in a separate tuple like, Tuple[Tuple[Tuple[graphanno.Node, ...]][Tuple[Tuple[int, ...]]]]